# How to create conversion/ lookup table with variable string length in C

Tags: c, arrays, tuples, converters

As an exercise, I want to read a subset of ASCII (like lower or uppercase letters) from standard input and translate it to Morse code (using dots and dashes).

The second, the conversion to Morse code, is my issue. Actually, only the data structure is the issue. I want to create some "efficient" lookup table of sort. I don't want to allocate an array of fixed length strings, like 5 chars for Morse code string, since those are an overkill for letters like 'e' ( one dot or "dit").

Also, I don't know, whether to create an injektive conversion from letters to morse or to convert to lower/upper case first and then translate to morse. Maybe, this should be considered in the remarks you give.

What did I come up with till now?
An array of structs:

```
    typedef struct conversion_table{
            char *abc;
            char *ABC;
            char *morse;
    };
```

this I imagined to use like:

```
    conversion_table *morse_table;
```

that would basically just create an array of tuples, if I understand it correctly. Then I would have to initialize the tuples with data like:

```
    morse_table[0]->abc   = "a";
    morse_table[0]->ABC   = "A";
    morse_table[0]->morse = ".-";
```

There could be a possibility of a linked-list implementation but, from my perspective, that would add unnecessary complexity.

Then, the actual conversion is a mystery to me as well, but that, I want to figure out on myself.

This question should serve as a brainstorming with pieces of code maybe, but **not a definitive solution**. Also, I would like to note, that I have done a fair amount of research (actually reading some implementations in Linux programs and reading Stack Overflow) but the ideas were in my eyes not that pretty or elegant if you want.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In the second paragraph, your second ('issue'?) comes before your first whatever it is.  Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?  If 64-bit, you are looking at a serious case of premature optimization because the pointers will occupy 8 bytes each, more than the fixed-length strings need.  I'd argue the same for a 32-bit platform, though it isn't quite as clear cut.

Comment: I don't see a need for optimization, but you could replace this entire concept of a look up table with a function, assuming Morse code has some sort of pattern

Comment: Hmmm, maybe this actually is a premature optimization. Quite right on a 64-bit machine. I didn't realize, the pointer takes so much space as well, just forgot it completely.
How would you mitigate the problem? Would you just create an array of arrays and not use the struct at all?

Comment: Yes, I thought about a switch statement, but that was ugly and lengthy as well. Morse code doesn't have any pattern that would greatly simplify things (or I don't know about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should radically simplify your data structure, reducing its size and avoiding any need for dynamic memory allocation. You also need to give a name to the `typedef` type:

```
typedef struct Morse
{
    char letter;
    char morse[7];
} Morse;
```

You can then initialize 26 letters, 10 digits and sundry other characters statically:

```
static const Morse morse[] =
{
    { 'A', ".-"     },
    ...
    { 'Z', "--.."   },
    ...
};
```

Your lookup code should convert lower-case to upper-case (or you can encode lower-case in the table and convert upper-case to lower-case).  With C99 or above, you can simplify things further:

```
static const char morse[][8] =
{
    ['A'] = ".-",
    ...
    ['Z'] = "--..",
    ...
};
```

Note that each entry in either the structure or the array uses just 8 bytes, which is as much as one pointer on a 64-bit platform and two points on a 32-bit platform, and if you do dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` etc), you have more overhead to worry about — a typical 64-bit `malloc()` uses 16 bytes when you request a single byte (or you request some larger number of bytes, such as 7; it increments by blocks of 16 bytes allocated).  So, using the pointers will undoubtedly take more space in this context than simply using small arrays of characters.

---

#### Working code

Not perfect; I'm not convinced about using `----` for blank, but using the data from [David C Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24503511/15168) and the C99 designated initializers yields this code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static char morse[][7] =
{
    ['A'] = ".-",
    ['B'] = "-...",
    ['C'] = "-.-.",
    ['D'] = "-..",
    ['E'] = ".",
    ['F'] = "..-.",
    ['G'] = "--.",
    ['H'] = "....",
    ['I'] = "..",
    ['J'] = ".---",
    ['K'] = "-.-",
    ['L'] = ".-..",
    ['M'] = "--",
    ['N'] = "-.",
    ['O'] = "---",
    ['P'] = ".--.",
    ['Q'] = "--.-",
    ['R'] = ".-.",
    ['S'] = "...",
    ['T'] = "-",
    ['U'] = "..-",
    ['V'] = "...-",
    ['W'] = ".--",
    ['X'] = "-..-",
    ['Y'] = "-.--",
    ['Z'] = "--..",

    ['0'] = "-----",
    ['1'] = ".----",
    ['2'] = "..---",
    ['3'] = "...--",
    ['4'] = "....-",
    ['5'] = ".....",
    ['6'] = "-....",
    ['7'] = "--...",
    ['8'] = "---..",
    ['9'] = "----.",

    ['.'] = ".-.-.-",
    [','] = "--..--",
    ['?'] = "..--..",
    ['\''] = ".----.",
    ['!'] = "-.-.--",
    ['/'] = "-..-.",
    ['('] = "-.--.",
    [')'] = "-.--.-",
    ['&'] = ".-...",
    [':'] = "---...",
    [';'] = "-.-.-.",
    ['='] = "-...-",
    ['+'] = ".-.-.",
    ['-'] = "-....-",
    ['_'] = "..--.-",
    ['\\'] = ".-..-.",
    ['$'] = "...-..-",
    ['@'] = ".--.-.",
    [' '] = "----",

};

enum { MAX_MORSE = sizeof(morse) / sizeof(morse[0]) };

static char *prompt(FILE *fp, const char *prompt, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
  printf("%s", prompt);
  fflush(0);
  return fgets(buffer, buflen, fp);
}

static void print_morse(FILE *fp, const char *buffer, const char *pad1, const char *pad2)
{
  int c;
  const char *pad = pad1;
  int col = 0;
  for (int i = 0; (c = buffer[i]) != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if (col == 0)
    {
      fputs(pad, fp);
      col += strlen(pad);
      pad = pad2;
    }
    putc(' ', fp);
    col++;
    c = toupper(c);
    if (c < MAX_MORSE && morse[c][0] != '\0')
    {
      fputs(morse[c], fp);
      col += strlen(morse[c]);
    }
    else
    {
      putc(c, fp);
      col++;
    }
    if (col > 72)
    {
      putc('\n', fp);
      col = 0;
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char buffer[256];
  while (prompt(stdin, "Message? ", buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 0)
  {
    printf("Text: %s", buffer);
    print_morse(stdout, buffer, "Code:", "     ");
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

```
$ make remorse
gcc -g -O3 -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration -Werror remorse.c -o remorse
$ ./remorse
Message? What the !@#$%^&*()-_=+\|[]{};:'"<>?,./ are you doing?
Text: What the !@#$%^&*()-_=+\|[]{};:'"<>?,./ are you doing?
Code: .-- .... .- - ---- - .... . ---- -.-.-- .--.-. # ...-..- % ^ .-... *
      -.--. -.--.- -....- ..--.- -...- .-.-. .-..-. | [ ] { } -.-.-. ---...
      .----. " < > ..--.. --..-- .-.-.- -..-. ---- .- .-. . ---- -.-- ---
      ..- ---- -.. --- .. -. --. ..--.. 
Message? The quick brown fox jumped of the lazy dog.
Text: The quick brown fox jumped of the lazy dog.
Code: - .... . ---- --.- ..- .. -.-. -.- ---- -... .-. --- .-- -. ---- ..-.
      --- -..- ---- .--- ..- -- .--. . -.. ---- --- ..-. ---- - .... . ----
      .-.. .- --.. -.-- ---- -.. --- --. .-.-.- 
Message? You get $9,876,543.21 at most.
Text: You get $9,876,543.21 at most.
Code: -.-- --- ..- ---- --. . - ---- ...-..- ----. --..-- ---.. --... -....
      --..-- ..... ....- ...-- .-.-.- ..--- .---- ---- .- - ---- -- --- ...
      - .-.-.- 
Message? 
$
```

Comment: This looks pretty I guess. I have to digest it a bit, will use it in the code and then report back with the complete solution. Thank you for the nice welcome to Stack Overflow! :-)

Comment: Ok, that explanation displays some in-depth understanding of things, good! The both your solutions are very nice. The first one maybe more "pedantic" in a good way. I guess, for the morse array, you would only need to write 5, since Morse code really only uses a number of five dashes or dots at most, but that is just nit-picking what in the end doesn't mean anything in this particular instance.

Comment: Having looked at Wikipedia for Morse code and seen that even the digits are only 5 characters long (but you'd want to use `char morse[6];` to allow for the terminating null), then my array sizes are slightly bigger than necessary, but the wastage is minimal, even so.  Using the slightly smaller size would save barely anything except in the most cramped of embedded systems.

Comment: Yes, I meant char morse[5] as in #{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} = 6. We both meant the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out there are more nuts in the world that have taken on this challenge as an exercise. While you can do a straight lookup table, there are some fairly slick ways to use character arrays to preform the translation as well. The following is an example of a function that will take an input character value as the argument and return the morse encoding as a string. You might find the conversions useful:

```
char *
chr2morse (int chi) {

    char *idx = NULL;
    char *mcode = NULL;

    char *morse[] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
    char *morsedigit[] = {"-----",".----","..---","...--","....-",".....","-....","--...","---..","----."};
    char *morsepunctcode[] = {".-.-.-","--..--","..--..",".----.","-.-.--","-..-.","-.--.","-.--.-",".-...","---...","-.-.-.","-...-",".-.-.","-....-","..--.-",".-..-.","...-..-",".--.-.","----"};
    char morsepunctchar[] = ".,?'!/()&:;=+-_\"$@ ";
    char *mptr = morsepunctchar;

    // char *morseprosigns[] = {".-...","wait","-.-","ok2send","........","error","...-.-","endtx","...-.","understood","-.-.-","starttx"};

    switch (chi) {

        case 'A' ... 'Z':
            mcode = morse [chi-'A'];
            break;
        case 'a' ... 'z':
            mcode = morse [chi-'a'];
            break;
        case '0' ... '9':
            mcode = morsedigit [chi-'0'];
            break;
        case ' ':
            mcode =  "---- ";   // word boundary char
            break;
        case '<':
            mcode = "-.-.-";    // start of transmission
            break;
        case '>':
            mcode = "...-.-";   // end of transmission
            break;
        case '\n':
            mcode = "\n";
            break;
    }
    idx = strchr (morsepunctchar, chi);
    if (idx)
        mcode = morsepunctcode [(int)(idx-mptr)];

    return mcode;
}
```

Essentially you just pass the input char from the keyboard or file to `char2morse` and get the morse encoding returned.

Comment: Yes, this is also quite nice and probably more real-world oriented but is not that elegant as the former answer from my perspective. Thank you anyway, I might reflect it in the other parts of the program.

Comment: It would be hard to beat anything Mr. Leffler provides. I just like the fact that arrays were indexed to correspond to the character at interest. type `A` and the proper Morse string is indexed appropriately. If nothing else, you will want the start of transmission, end of transmission and word boundary encodings. The punctuation is nice as well. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, the start/ end of transmission is a good point. I am still working on the solution in my free time, so it may take a while. I will report back when the code is done.